# Fitnesse : How to run specific tests across multiple Test suites

Tags: fitnesse, test-suite, fitsharp

We use Fitnesse [FitSharp] and we have a requirement for a single fit test that will call and run individual tests that span multiple suites.

I know we could put it in a batch file and run individual tests from there

C:\Fitnesse\dotnet4\Runner.exe -r fitnesse.fitserver.TestRunner,C:\fitnesse\dotnet4\fit.dll localhost 8090 Suite1.Level2.PartialUpdateTest

C:\Fitnesse\dotnet4\Runner.exe -r fitnesse.fitserver.TestRunner,C:\fitnesse\dotnet4\fit.dll localhost 8090 Suite1.Level1.FullUpdateTest

etc

but would prefer to keep the configuration of this within the fit test environment

What we have in mind is a single Fit Test [Regression Suite] that will serve as a container for other fit tests. [A container of Fit Test bookmarks if you will]

localhost:8090\Regression.RunAllFastCoreTestsAcrossAllSuites.

We do not want to go down the route of creating copies of individual tests within existing suites nor is a reorg of the existing suite structure feasible. The Regression suite will probably be updated regularly as new tests are developed.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Liam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using Suite Tags for this?  Suite Tags will allow you to mark the tests for specific purposes.  You can then use Suite Filters when you run your tests

```
http://localhost:8080/FrontPage?suite&suiteFilter=Regression
```

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.TestSuites.TagsAndFilters for more information.

It does have the downside that you can't see the one page, but we find it very effective.

Comment: Dan, thanks for your help. This worked perfectly. We created a page and saved the link as on a single page containing the 2 or 3 tags that are of interest to us. servername:8090/ManualTestSuite.AnotherSuite?responder=suite&suiteFilter=Regression

Answer (score 4):

You could use !see to create a suite page containing references to each test page, e.g.:

```
!see Suite1.Level2.PartialUpdateTest
!see Suite1.Level1.FullUpdateTest
```

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupCrossReference

Comment: Andy, Thanks for your quick response. I'll give it a go and see if its suitable and mark as answered then.

Comment: One note.  In the current release there is a bug that !see doesn't respect disabling pages.  So you might turn off the test at the page, but the test still runs because it is in a !see.  It might be the same for Suite Filters or Suite Queries as well.

Comment: Andy, thanks for your answer, its good to know about the existance !see command although in my case using suite filters was more suitable